# How do I get an image to move until it gets to a specific point in the window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zelle-graphics

Right now I have some code in Python using Zelle graphics that has a robot image and some text scrolling upward. When the user clicks on the window, the program ends.

What I'm trying to do is have pieces of the robot image come in from opposite sides of the window (The head moving down from the top, the eyes moving up from the bottom, and the ears moving in from the left and right). They would stop moving once they come together to form the completed image.

After that, I want the text to come in from the left hand side and stop once it gets to the center of the screen, underneath the image. I don't want the animation to start until the user clicks on the window.

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
    from graphics import *
    from random import randint
    from time import sleep
    screen=GraphWin("Logo",500,700);
    screen.setBackground("#b3e2bf");
    #---------logo-----------

    robotHead=Image(Point(250,250),"robotHead.png");
    robotHead.draw(screen);

    robotEyes=Image(Point(250,310),"robotEyes.png");
    robotEyes.draw(screen);

    robotLeftEar=Image(Point(150,290),"robotLeftEar.png");
    robotLeftEar.draw(screen);

    robotRightEar=Image(Point(350,290),"robotRightEar.png");
    robotRightEar.draw(screen);


    #--------credits-----------
    programmer=Point(250,515);
    lineOne=Text(programmer,"Programmer Name");
    lineOne.draw(screen);

    className=Point(250,535);
    lineTwo=Text(className,"CSC 211");
    lineTwo.draw(screen);

    date=Point(250,555);
    lineThree=Text(date,"November 30th, 2017");
    lineThree.draw(screen);

    copyrightName=Point(250,575);
    lineFour=Text(copyrightName,"Copyright Line");
    lineFour.draw(screen);


    while screen.checkMouse()==None:
        robotHead.move(0,-1);
        robotEyes.move(0,-1);
        robotLeftEar.move(0,-1);
        robotRightEar.move(0,-1);
        lineOne.move(0,-1);
        lineTwo.move(0,-1);
        lineThree.move(0,-1);
        lineFour.move(0,-1);
        sleep(0.1);
    screen.close();
```

Comment: you could check image position `robotHead.anchor.getY()` and move only if it is not on expected position. You could use variables to control which part to move ie. `move_className = False`. If head is on expected position then you can set `move_className = True`.

Comment: `Python` doesn't need `;`  at the end of line

Comment: BTW: read [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - prefered lower case names like `robot_head`, add spaces after `,` and around `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `robotHead.anchor.getY()` and `robotHead.anchor.getX()` to check current position and move it only if it is not on expected position.

You can also use variables with `True/False` to control which element has to move (or even which element to show on screen). At start you should have `moveHead = True`and  `moveLineOne = False`. When `head` is on expected position then you can change `moveHead = False` and  `moveLineOne = True`.

BTW: `graphics` has function `update(frames_per_second)` to control speed of animation and you don't need `sleep()`. Besides `update()` executes some functions which `graphics` may need for correct work. (`graphics` documentation: [Controlling Display Updates (Advanced)](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node15.html))

Speed 25-30 FPS is enough for human eye to see smooth animation (and it may uses less CPU power than 60 FPS).

Simple example

```
from graphics import *
from random import randint
from time import sleep

screen = GraphWin("Logo", 500, 700)

# --- objects ---

robot_head = Image(Point(250, 250), "robotHead.png")
robot_head.draw(screen)

programmer = Point(250, 515)
line_one = Text(programmer, "Programmer Name") 
#line_one.draw(screen) # don't show at start

# --- control objects ---

move_robot_head = True # move head at start
move_line_one = False  # don't move text at start

# --- mainloop ---

while not screen.checkMouse(): # while screen.checkMouse() is None:

    if move_robot_head: # if move_robot_head == True:
        # check if head is on destination position
        if robot_head.anchor.getY() <= 100:
            # stop head
            move_robot_head = False

            # show text
            line_one.draw(screen)

            # move text 
            move_line_one = True
        else:
            # move head
            robot_head.move(0, -10)

    if move_line_one: # if move_line_one == True:
        # check if head is on destination position
        if line_one.anchor.getY() <= 150:
            # stop text
            move_programmer = False
        else:
            # move text
            line_one.move(0, -10)

    # control speed of animation        
    update(30) # 30 FPS (frames per second)

# --- end ---

screen.close()
```